# Managing multiple screens on Windows (10)

Tags: windows, laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi, tv

I have a setup of Laptop + external monitor that is constantly plugged in, I use DisplayPort cable and have Windows set to "extend" on the 2nd screen and it works well.

Now I also have a TV that I occasionally plug into the laptop using HDMI cable and whenever that happens I would like Windows to automatically disable extending the screen to the 2nd (external) monitor and instead switch to displaying everything on the TV screen only. Is this possible to achieve?

Currently each time I want to switch over to the TV I need to first manually unplug my external monitor, then plug the HDMI cable and then change the settings under ctrl+P menu to "Second Screen Only" to get it to work. Is there a way for it to happen automatically?

Thank you.

Comment: You should ask on Software Recommendations site